# ImageMagick C# Exception : no pixels defined in cache

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I'm trying to create a new image with a specific `ColorType` (it does the same thing with `ColorSpace`) and I have this error: `no pixels defined in cache`.

I'm not trying to load/read an existing image. I'm not trying to save the image. I'm just trying to set a property of the object. I don't even understand why there would be an exception thrown here.

Here is the code that is failing:

```cs
MagickImage img = new();
img.ColorType = ColorType.GrayscaleAlpha;
```

Here is the exception that is thrown:

[image]

If I remove the line that is failing, everything works fine. But I want to create a Png image with only gray and alpha channel. Maybe I'm not doing that properly.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is thrown because you cannot set the `ColorType` when you did not load any pixel data. You will need to first `Read` an image before you can set that property.

Comment: Oh I see. That kind of make sense. I wanted to set up all the format and stuff before because that's how most the tools I used work. Thanks for your help!